# ElasticSearch jdbc river

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to feed data into Elastic Search using jdbc river but this river is not getting all the data. I have 450000 records in MySQL table but in ES i get only about 230000 records.

Here is my ES river setting:

```
 curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "test",
        "password" : "test",
        "sql" : "select * from test" },
        "index":{
        "index" : "test",
        "bulk_size":600,
        "max_bulk_requests":10,
        "bulk_timeout":"5s",
        "autocommit":"true"  
        }
}'
```

I have looked in Elastic Search documentation but i could not find the solution.
I am using river-jdbc-1.1.0.2 version.

Comment: 1. What version of elasticsearch are you using? 2. What are your elasticsearch JVM configurations? 3. Did you check if you have enough space for you cluster between data and tmp data?

Answer (score 0):

You updated like you need to index 450000 . and your script have the following parameters

```
    "bulk_size":600,
    "max_bulk_requests":10,
    "bulk_timeout":"5s"
```

Remove bulk_timeout 5 sec and decrease bulk size and max_bulk_request. Since you are indexing 450000 documents to elastic search some where data is missing with these parameters.

Suppose if you are not mentioning the above parameters even though we missed records.
So the following are the optimal parameters to fetch the data using river to control es river requests to index data.

```
    "bulk_size":160,
    "max_bulk_requests":5,
```

Previously I had this issue. I solved using above params in my river script.if you apply the above params it will work for sure.try this once.

hope it helps!